# To compare the values responding the different categories for each group(using groupby)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I tried to apply rules for the status of each group.
The rule will be:
If the values of corner A & D are both smaller than the values of corner B & C, the status for this group will be pass. Otherwise, it's gonna be failed.

Here is the dataframe, df, below.

```
Item    Corner   Value   
A-001     A       0.1
A-001     B       0.5
A-001     C       0.4
A-001     D       0.1
A-002     A       0.3
A-002     B       0.6
A-002     C       0.2
A-002     D       0.1
```

And the expected result:

```
Item    Corner   Value   Status
A-001     A       0.1      pass (corner A &D < corner B&C)
A-001     B       0.5      pass
A-001     C       0.4      pass
A-001     D       0.1      pass
A-002     A       0.3      fail (corner A > corner C, so the status of this group failed)
A-002     B       0.6      fail
A-002     C       0.2      fail
A-002     D       0.1      fail
```

So, here's my solution, but the function is still incomplete...

```
def rule_status(df):
    
    corner_a = df.loc[df['corner'] == 'A', 'Value']
    corner_b = df.loc[df['corner'] == 'B', 'Value']
    corner_c = df.loc[df['corner'] == 'C', 'Value']
    corner_d = df.loc[df['corner'] == 'D', 'Value']

    if max(corner_a, corner_d) < min(corner_b, corner_c):
        return 'pass' 
    else:
        return 'fail'    

df.groupby('Item').apply(lambda x :rule_status(x))
```

However, in the function, I just get a series of values for corner_a corner_b corner_c & corner_d, instead of the specific value for each corner.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the data then compare:

```
pivoted = df.pivot('Item', 'Corner', 'Value')

mask = pivoted[['A','D']].max(axis=1) < pivoted[['B','C']].min(axis=1)

df['Status'] = np.where(df['Item'].map(mask), 'pass', 'fail')
```

Output:

```
    Item Corner  Value Status
0  A-001      A    0.1   pass
1  A-001      B    0.5   pass
2  A-001      C    0.4   pass
3  A-001      D    0.1   pass
4  A-002      A    0.3   fail
5  A-002      B    0.6   fail
6  A-002      C    0.2   fail
7  A-002      D    0.1   fail
```

Comment: Actually, there are more than 4 corners each of the group, and the comparison for the status are way more complicated than that.  But, I just tried to simply the question tho...

Comment: Complicated or not, you should be doing that on `pivoted`: `mask = pivoted.apply(lambda r: max(r['A'], r['D']) < min(r['B'], r['C']), axis=1)`. That said, you should think how your comparison can be vectorized (as in my answer).

Comment: Thanks. not sure it's gonna work or not. But, really appreciate ur solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Status'] = df['Item'].map(
    df.loc[df['Corner'].isin(['A', 'D'])].groupby('Item')['Value'].max()
      .lt(df.loc[df['Corner'].isin(['B', 'C'])].groupby('Item')['Value'].min())
      .replace({True: 'pass', False: 'fail'}))
print(df)

# Output:
    Item Corner  Value Status
0  A-001      A    0.1   pass
1  A-001      B    0.5   pass
2  A-001      C    0.4   pass
3  A-001      D    0.1   pass
4  A-002      A    0.3   fail
5  A-002      B    0.6   fail
6  A-002      C    0.2   fail
7  A-002      D    0.1   fail
```